# Thousands of Task <A3E18896-7B51-4481-A373-6C52DDD8C3BF>.<193> finished with error - code: -1002. How to find where this is being emitted?

Tags: xcode

I've tried my best to find where this is coming from, but I'm at a loss.

I thought maybe images were falling to load somehow. Nope.

I know 1002 is an error related to NSURLConnection, but my Logs don't reference anything related to an NSURLConnection. I've received 1002 before, but the logs always mention NSURLConnection as well.

Here's an example of what I'm looking at:

```
2018-05-18 14:59:38.406606-0600 MyApp[9635:2490206] Task <A3E18896-7B51-4481-A373-6C52DDD8C3BF>.<193> finished with error - code: -1002
2018-05-18 14:59:38.406921-0600 MyApp[9635:2490206] Task <D0CD9879-1FF8-4514-9DE7-2E4EB6492882>.<194> finished with error - code: -1002
2018-05-18 14:59:38.461969-0600 MyApp[9635:2490208] Task <D784F57A-8015-42E9-AC6B-B43B77344113>.<195> finished with error - code: -1002
```

Is there anyway to set a breakpoint on these? I've tried creating symbolic breakpoints but I don't know what to set it on. It doesn't seem to give me any specific function that I can use as the symbol.